# How to convert a string into datetime with format directives from another Timezone with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, django, linux, datetime

I have function in my Django application that pulls informations from SSH. I get a raw date string like the following (French language):

> 'mar. 27 mars 2012 17:51:42 CEST'

My issue is that I need to convert this string to a datetime object before passing it to update one of my model, but I get an error.

```
ssh_output = 'mar. 27 mars 2012 17:51:42 CEST'
my_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(ssh_output,"%a. %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S CEST")
```

Above code throws an exception:

> time data 'mar. 27 mars 2012 17:51:42 CEST' does not match format '%a.
> %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S CEST'

I'm confused because `locale.getlocale()`  outputs: "

> ('fr_FR', 'UTF-8')

But testing datetime format with `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")` outputs (English language):

> Wed 08 July 2020 15:46:11

Also, all date format directives seems correct (plus literal strings '.' and 'CEST'):

- **%a** : Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name.
- **%d** : Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
- **%B** : Month as locale’s full name.
- **%Y** : Year with century as a decimal number.
- **%H** : Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
- **%M** : Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
- **%S** : Second as a zero-padded decimal number.

So it seems that raw datetime string grabbed from SSH output 'mar. 27 mars 2012 17:51:42 CEST' can't be parsed/converted because it does not match current timezone...

How can I convert this raw datetime string into datetime in this case?

Comment: reads like multiple questions in one. first of all, remove the dot from the format string; `"%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S CEST"`. second, you could try to set the locale, `import locale` and then `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')`. third, `%Z` likely won't parse 'CEST' correctly, you'll need to come up with something else for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse `CEST` to the correct timezone, you could split the ssh output into the datetime part and the timezone part. After that you can apply a mapping dict:

```
import datetime
import dateutil

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')

ssh_output = 'mar. 27 mars 2012 17:51:42 CEST'

# assuming timezone abbreviation separated by space
parts = ssh_output.split(' ')
timestr, tzstr = ' '.join(parts[:-1]), parts[-1]

# create a custom mapping dict
tzmapping = {'CEST': dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/Paris')}

my_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr,"%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
my_datetime = my_datetime.replace(tzinfo=tzmapping[tzstr])
# datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 27, 17, 51, 42, tzinfo=tzfile('Europe/Paris'))
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'dateutil' has no attribute 'tz'. Installed from python3 venv: pip install python-dateutil. Is it the same module?

Comment: "from dateutil import tz" would fix this